# Can't install Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I'm trying to install Rails on OS X Lion and get the message below. I've installed Ruby and updated to the rubyGems version 1.8.5 too.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/opt/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
make
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10 -I/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10 -I. -I/opt/local/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -O2 -arch x86_64  -fno-common -pipe -fno-common  -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -c parser.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [parser.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.0/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your gcc is missing. Seems to happen in Lion. Try reinstalling XCode and command line tools, or install one via [Homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38222/how-do-i-install-gcc-via-homebrew)